# Creating an instance of a type using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I am trying to use reflection to create an instance of one of my classes. The interface for the class (IInstructions) has one variable shown below.

```
    string[] Operands { get; set; }
```

I am trying to create an instance of this class using reflection that has the operand variables set. The code I have got so far is shown below.

```
        Assembly[] assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
        Console.WriteLine(operands[0]);
        foreach (Assembly a in assemblies)
        {
            Type[] typeArray = a.GetTypes();
            foreach (Type type in typeArray)
            {
                if (opcode.Equals(type.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    Object dynamicObj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                    instruction = (IInstructionWithOperand)dynamicObj;

                }
            }
        }
```

This, so far searches through the loaded assemblies and retrieves the correct assembly and type for that assembly. However, I'm unsure how to set the variable for this type and correctly create an instance of it?

Comment: Note that it is often a bad practice to have a get/set property of array type. Someone can set the property and then someone else can get the property and mutate the array, and both of those things might not be what you want.  Consider having a get-only property that returns an `IEnumerable<string>` instead of a `string[]`.

Answer (score 0):

If the type is always `IInstructionWithOperand` then you could declare

```
IInstructionWithOperand instruction;
```

and then assign it exactly as you have:

```
instruction = (IInstructionWithOperand)dynamicObj;
```

Or, suppose all of the code above is within a function. You could make `IInstructionWithOperand` the return type of the function, like

```
IInstructionWithOperand GetInstruction(string opcode)
{
    Assembly[] assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
    Console.WriteLine(operands[0]);
    foreach (Assembly a in assemblies)
    {
        Type[] typeArray = a.GetTypes();
        foreach (Type type in typeArray)
        {
            if (opcode.Equals(type.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                Object dynamicObj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                return (IInstructionWithOperand)dynamicObj;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You don't have to declare a variable within the function. When you call the function, it will look like this:

```
var instruction = GetInstruction(someOpCode);
```

and the declared type of `instruction` will be `IInstructionWithOperand`.

That's probably a good idea anyway because it will keep parts of your code separate. One function creates an instance of a class that implements `IInstructionWithOperand`, and another function (or class) uses it to do something.

Comment: This seems like a good start; you'll need to return something on the error path, or throw though.

Comment: The code above is part of a function, which has two variables passed into it. One for the opcode (which is used to find the type as I've already done in my code) the second variable is the operand which needs to be saved as part of the class that i'm creating an instance of, I just don't know how to properly set the it within this function using reflection?